# wrap text with div excluding all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a problem which I have been trying to solve for past 2 days, but couldn't solve it.

**Problem:**

I have a HTML as

```
      <div class="string-box">
         Text 1 wrap me
         <span class="inner-span">Don't search me</span>
         <span class="inner-span">Identical text</span>
         Identical text
         substring match
         <span class="inner-span">Don't search substring match</span>
         <br>
         Finally wrap me
      </div>
```

I want to wrap the content has below

```
      <div class="string-box">
         <span> Text 1 wrap me </span>
         <span class="inner-span">Don't search me</span>
         <span class="inner-span">Identical text</span>
         <span>Identical text</span>
         <span>substring match</span>
         <span class="inner-span">Don't search substring match</span>
         <br>
         <span>Finally wrap me</span>
      </div>
```

**What I have tried**

a) I firstly tried to search for string in the html and used string replace to replace the string with wrapped string.
    The problem with this approach is that it replaces things in child too..

b) I tried cloning the node and removing all child , but then I am lost with the position of the string.

c) I tried the following code to replace textNode, but I ended up getting HTML

```
   $('.string-box').contents().filter(function(){ 
        return this.nodeType == 3; 
   }).each(function(){ 
        this.nodeValue = '<span>'+this.nodeValue+'</span>';                   
   })
```

Thanks in advance for you time & help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is close, however the `nodeValue` cannot contain HTML - hence why it gets encoded in your attempt. Instead you can `wrap()` the textNode in HTML, like this:

```
$('.string-box').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<span />');
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wm475mL1/)

*Update*

Here's a fix for occasions where the nodeValue contains a line break, and you want to wrap each line of the node in its own `span`:

```
$('.string-box').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
}).each(function() {
    var $spans = this.nodeValue.trim().split(/\r?\n/).map(function(i, v) {
        return $('<span />', { text: i + ' ' });
    });
    $(this).replaceWith($spans);
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wm475mL1/4/)

Comment: Hmm, can you explain why you use `filter` AND `each`? Two loops witch can be done in only one ...

Comment: but the current approach still find the inner content (inner tag)and replace it :(

Comment: There is an issue with your solution : you wrap `<span>Identical text substring match</span>` in a single span, the OP would like `<span>Identical text </span><span>substring match</span>` ou need to wrap if `\n`

Answer (score 2):

Just do it only in an `each` and you're fine. No need for `filter` the elements first. And you can use jQuery to `wrap` the content in a `span`.

```
$('.string-box').contents().each(function() {
    if( this.nodeType == 3 )
         $(this).wrap('<span />');
});
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/fsey4jdz/)

Answer (score 2):

As you already have a jQuery answer, allow me to offer a plain JavaScript alternative:

```
var stringBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.string-box'),
    stringBoxArray = Array.from(stringBoxes),
    newElement = document.createElement('span'),
    clone,
    children;

stringBoxArray.forEach(function(box){
  children = Array.from( box.childNodes ).filter(function(child){
    return child.nodeType === 3;
  }).forEach(function (text) {
    clone = newElement.cloneNode();
    text.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, text);
    clone.appendChild(text);
  });
});
```